# How to config devise to make user login after register even without confirm email via email link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use devise (2.0.4) to setup user register and sign-in functions. Now I want to make user be able to sign in after sign up. Event a confirmation email send to his email box. Just mark "This user is not confirmed." How to config ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this will also solve the problem. Which one to chose?

```
def active_for_authentication?
  true
end
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Overriding `confirmation_required?` will make confirmable not work (no email sent). `active_for_authentication?` is how you override your User with "special conditions" and is actually used by confirmable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add overrided  method `confirmation_required?` directly to your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def confirmation_required?
    false
  end
end
```